# URLs fine in database but wrong in output

Tags: urls, server

I have my URLs all right in the database (at least, "Better Search & Replace" doesn´t find the faulty ones, neither does phpMyAdmin), but in the frontend they are messed up.

Basically http:// is missing the : so images won´t load correctly, links are wrong etc. pp.

Home and Website URL are fine in the backend and *some* images and links are working. I already deleted and rebuilt the .htaccess, so it´s not about that either, I think.

What might cause this behaviour? Strangely configured server of the client?

**Update 1:** I tried disabling all plugins and switching to a standard theme. This didn´t change anything.

Comment: If it's on NGinx, there may also be a server config file in addition to .htaccess. Outside of that, I would switch to a default theme & deactivate all plugins, then check - using an Incognito window or a http header checker so your browser cache doesn't come into play - and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: You might also try viewing the "Settings > Permalinks" page (just a pageload, no need to make changes or save) to refresh permalinks.

Comment: Media urls are generated dynamically.  Check out the urls in the Media Library.  If the image urls are good in there, then you probably have a plugin that is re-generating the urls incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a further look into that and come back on this again...

Comment: Just looking into it. The URLs are all fine in the media library, so I will give the plugins a try now.

Comment: Ok, even with all plugins disabled and Twenty Seventeen (freshly installed) as a theme, the error is still there. Strange stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was pretty strange. While only `http//` showed up in the URLs the database fields for the corrupted URLs were `http://http//` which obviously resulted in the error. I did another search & replace for those "double http" and that fixed it in the end. Still no idea why this only happened to some URLs but I´m happy I figured it out.

So having a second look, two days later, sometimes is a valid solution. :-)